# Function Specified Value returns but in every column not just 1 in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Created a simple Function to return GST of an Items price thats entered.
Problem is it returns the correct Amount but has the correct amount for the ID Specified for every other item aswell. which is wrong.
Function is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_GSTPrice
(@ItemID INT)
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @GSTRate FLOAT
  SET @GSTRate = 0.1
  DECLARE @GSTFinal FLOAT

  SET @GSTFinal = (SELECT Price * (@GSTRate)
        FROM Products
        WHERE ItemID = @ItemID)

  RETURN @GSTFinal

  END
```

With Select Statement being:

```
 SELECT ItemDescription,
 dbo.fn_GSTPrice(1) AS GSTFinal
 FROM Items
```

Whats returned is:

```
  ItemDescription  | GST
  ----------------------
  Item1            | 25
  Item2            | 25
  Item3            | 25
  Item4            | 25
  Item5            | 25
  Item6            | 25
  Item7            | 25
  Item8            | 25
  Item9            | 25
  Item10           | 25
```

Item1 is ItemID(1) and So on.. and 25 is the GST amount for Item1
But why is the GST Value for ItemID(1) also showing up for the others that arent that ID.. And 25 isnt the GST Value for any of the others.?

What am i missing or dont understand?
I need it to show only the ItemID entered in the fn_GSTPrice().

**EDIT #1** : @joanolo answer is fine if i only want to check the GST of that 1 item... ever. but i want the result of whatever ID is entered in the parameter, Without having to change the WHERE clause every single time.

Example being :

```
SELECT Description, fn_GSTPrice(43) AS 'GST Total'
FROM Products
WHERE ItemID = (@ItemID entered into Parameter for GSTPrice)
```

Without having to change the WHERE clause to 1 or 43 or 13 or whatever i put in GSTPrice()??

Comment: The GST of Item1 is showing because that's what your are asking for. You probably would like to have `dbo.fn_GSTPrice(ItemID)` instead of `dbo.fn_GSTPrice(1)`.

Comment: I know why its showing  the gst for item1. But why is it also showing the gst for item1  where item2,3,4 etc are? Why doesnt it only show item1 and the gst for item1. Since im only asking for item1?

Comment: Because you didn't add a [`WHERE`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) clause telling the database you only want rows `WHERE ItemId=1`

Comment: Im not sure if youre looking at the actual post? There is a where clause... that specifies just that..?

Comment: There is *none* for the statement following the sentence *With Select Statement being:*

Comment: If i have a where clause in my function. Why do i need one in my select statement? That would mean i need an individual select statement for every item. Instead of the function only showing the itemID that is entered in its parameters in the select statement? Just makes the parameter for the function useless and could be removed? I must be missing something here because it makes no sense if thats the only way i can do it. Just seems like alot of querying.

Comment: Your function is evaluated *after* the `FROM` clause has been evaluated. The `SELECT` part of a query is not the *first* thing that is evaluated, even if it appears first. Why don't you just try putting the `WHERE` after the `FROM` and see what happens?

Comment: i cant get the      ` WHERE ` clause to get..        ` WHERE ItemID = (Whats entered in the parameter for fn_GSTPrice). ` it works if i say        ` WHERE ItemID = 1 `
But i dont want to have to create a seperate one for each item.